# Accessibility, have a text size swapper, can't get contrast swapper to work

Tags: jquery, css, accessibility

For the first time I'm building a website with some accessibility controls. I need the ability to set text size to small, default & large and to set contrast to normal, yellow on black and black on yellow. I'm an average front-end developer but don't often use js or jquery

My approach is to set some classes to the html "body" to deal with each case

I have written the following jquery:

```
// Accessibility 
// Check for cookies and set body class accordingly
if($.cookie("bodyclass-text")) {
      $("body").addClass($.cookie("bodyclass-text"));
    }
if($.cookie("bodyclass-contrast")) {
      $("body").addClass($.cookie("bodyclass-contrast"));
    }
// initialize the jquery code
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // add or remove classes to body as appropriate
  // return false keeps the browser from following the link's '#' target

  // Text size
  $("#defaultText").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("small-text");
    $("body").removeClass("large-text");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-text", null);
    return false;
  });
  $("#smallText").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("large-text");
    $("body").addClass("small-text");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-text", "small-text", { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    return false;
  });
  $("#largeText").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("small-text");
    $("body").addClass("large-text");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-text", "large-text", { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    return false;
  });

  // Contrast
  $("#defaultContrast").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("black-on-yellow");
    $("body").removeClass("yellow-on-black");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-contrast", null);
    return false;
  });
  $("#yellowOnBlack").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("black-on-yellow");
    $("body").addClass("yellow-on-black");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-contrast", "yellow-on-black", { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    return false;
  });
  $("#blackOnYellow").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("yellow-on-black");
    $("body").addClass("black-on-yellow");
    $.cookie("bodyclass-contrast", "black-on-yellow", { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    return false;
  });
});
```

So, for some reason the text sizer works but the contrast swapper doesn't. This could be a CSS problem, when I look at this in FireBug I think my body classes are being correctly set but I can't get the yellow on black or black on yellow to kick in. I've tried adding some large font sizes in there too which I know worked for my text css.

Here is my css in extract:

```
/* Accessibility options */
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #777;
    background: #fff;
}

body.yellow-on-black !important{
    color: yellow;
    background: black;
    font-size: 3em;
}

body.black-on-yellow !important{
    color: black;
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 3em;
}


body.small-text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

body.large-text {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

For completeness, my html looks like this:

```
<div id="defaultText"><a>Normal text</a></div>
<div id="smallText"><a>Smaller text</a></div>
<div id="largeText"><a>Larger text</a></div>
<p>
<div id="defaultContrast"><a>Default Contrast</a></div>
<div id="yellowOnBlack"><a>Yellow on Black</a></div>
<div id="blackOnYellow"><a>Black on Yellow</a></div>
```

Can anyone suggest how I go about resolving this issue?

Test web page is here: http://www.crossroadscare.hardingweb.net/index.php

The accessibility options are at the bottom of the right column.

Many thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Can you make a testcase, a smaller page that also demonstrates the problem and nothing else? On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for instance. It could be caused by the `!important`s in the wrong places, but it's difficult to debug other people's webpages like this.

Comment: By the way, silly question maybe, but why do you have `<a>` elements without attributes in the divs and onclick handlers on the divs? What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: It was those !important attributes that were somehow wrong. Removing them sorted this out. Thanks, well spotted!

Comment: Oh, OK, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two occurrences of `!important` in the CSS in places where they don't belong. Only individual properties can have `!important`, so these rules are therefore incorrect and will be skipped. Remove the `!important`s from

```css
body.yellow-on-black !important{
```

and

```css
body.black-on-yellow !important{
```

and add them to the individual properties if necessary. (It shouldn't be necessary though, only in borderline cases where you need to override CSS that has `!important` and that you can't change.)